# How to see system resource usage for one command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, monitoring

I am working on monitoring scripts for linux (ubuntu) hosts, I currently have 2 check CPU usage scripts and I want to know if there is a way to run a script (.sh or .rb file) and capture how much CPU/mem it required so that I can compare them and decide which one to run on my machines... How can I do this?! 
I know you can get the stats based on PID but the script is processed so fast that I cant get accurate stats with that method.. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663766/programmatic-resource-monitoring-per-process-in-linux) will help ?

Comment: A way would be to write a very simple c code (just calling `system` command, maybe) to execute the script and then work with that process.